# Access PHP SimpleXMLElement object

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have an object like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [url] => http://openclipart.org/people/jgm104/Expression_of_Emotions.svg
            [type] => image/svg+xml
            [length] => 485314
        )

)
```

How can I acces the url from there?

I tried `$photos->item[$i]->enclosure->{"@attributes]"}`
but it show only blank SimpleXMLElement objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can use method [SimpleXMLElement::attributes](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes) to get access for all options.

> $photos->item[$i]->attributes()->url

Answer (score 0):

You can acces to it this a way:

```
$photos->item[$i]->enclosure->attributes()["attributeName"];
```

or

```
$miAttrList = $photos->item[$i]->enclosure->attributes();
echo $miAttrList["attributeName"];
```